# Java Math/Rounding/Variable

Tags: java, math

If I have a double x4 = 20.85, how could I take the "85" part and make it into its own variable x5?

Comment: double x5=x4 - (int) x4;

Comment: @ControlAltDel That would give you `.85`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x5 = x4 % 1  It works to get any decimal from a whole number.